# Typescript | Pass type argument to another type with argument

Tags: typescript

I would like to do something like below

```js
type TypeA<T> = (initialValue: T) => { ... }

const someFunc: <T>(TypeA<T>) = (initalValue) => {...} // doesn't work

someFunc<string>('Hello World')
```

Not

```
const someFunc:TypeA<string> = (initalValue) => {...}
```

Is this feasible?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TypeA` is a generic type (that happens to be a function). To assign a generic function, you should change the definition of `TypeA`:

```
type TypeA = <T>(initialValue: T) => {  }

const someFunc: TypeA = (initalValue) => { return {} }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=55&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oB4YD4AUBLAdrsLgIYA2AauQK4QBcsAlCplAN5RQC+AUDwMYB7fAGdgUEYIC2EAGLV8-BnEhJUeQsHJUytZslYcAThGDUj+dl25QA9LagATQRBH4A5OIDugowGs+SRl5RTQxIwIAcxx3AAkIMjJBKAB1XzJHd0YgA)